# i can't align my navigation bar to the right

Tags: navigation

I can't align the nav-bar to right even after using the "mr-auto" class

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <div class="mr-auto"></div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I changed the syntax to the bootstrap 5.0 standard. mr-auto in bootstrap 4 is now ms-auto in bootstrap 5